# Unable to display Promoted Results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, promoted-results

I am indexing custom user data from my SQL repository and have mapped common managed properties with my crawled properties. I created a result source filtering this custom user data and have created a seperate search results page to display the data. All successful.

However when I try to display a few results as promoted results, I am not unable to do so. Below are teh steps I did till now

1. Indexed my people content source and mapped the PreferredName, Department, Jobtitle, WorkEmail managed properties.
2. Created a Result Source named "People Results" to filter results only from my custom content source.
3. Created a result type mapping where ContentSource="People Results" with results looking like "People Intent Item"
4. Created a Query Rule at site collection level with Actions as Adding a result block as image below
   [image]
5. Created a search results page to display all results for the querytext with item display template as "People Intent Item"

Not sure why but my promoted results are not getting displayed. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After you created these managed properties, whether you ran a full crawl for your content source. If not, please run a full crawl for your content source. After finishing, test again.

Comment: Yes I did. However still the same issues. I can get results in the page I created that displays people results but not in the promoted results block.